# How to enable Google Maps and generate an API key using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform

I've been trying to spin up a project from scratch over the Christmas break to automate the creation of my home network, one of those components is the [Ubiquiti Controller](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B017T2QB22/) which requires a [Google Maps API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key) to plot devices onto maps.

I've been able to automate the creation of the project using Terraform:

```
resource "google_project" "slaterfamily_network" {
  depends_on      = ["data.google_organization.org"]
  name            = "Slater Family Network"
  project_id      = "slaterfamily-network"
  org_id          = "${data.google_organization.org.id}"
  billing_account = "${var.billing_account}"
}

resource "google_project_iam_binding" "account_owner" {
  project = "${google_project.slaterfamily_network.project_id}"

  # It's important to specify ALL members, as this replaces them:
  #   https://twitter.com/devopsreact/status/840233052194320384
  members = [
    "user:richard@slaterfamily.name",
    "serviceAccount:${data.google_service_account.terraform_service_account.email}",
  ]

  role = "roles/owner"
}
```

This works fine for configuring Google Cloud DNS, however, I can't seem to find a way of enabling Google Maps and generating an API key, the following statements enable the Service Usage API, however it fails enabling the Maps API:

```
resource "google_project_service" "service_usage" {
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  service = "serviceusage.googleapis.com"
}

resource "google_project_service" "maps" {
  depends_on = ["google_project_service.service_usage"]
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  service = "maps.googleapis.com"
}
```

With this error:

```
google_project_service.maps: Error enabling service: failed to issue request: googleapi: Error 403: The caller does not have permission, forbidden
```

Which after tracing the HTTP calls gives me the following, formatted as cURL for ease of reproduction:

```
curl -H 'Host: serviceusage.googleapis.com' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'authorization: Bearer {{ BEARER_TOKEN }}' -H 'user-agent: google-api-go-client/0.5 Terraform/0.11.7 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-google/1.20.0' --data-binary "{}" --compressed 'https://serviceusage.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/slaterfamily-network/services/maps.googleapis.com:enable?alt=json&prettyPrint=false'
```

Which results in:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The caller does not have permission",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to create the api key after enabling the api?

Comment: It's not yet possible to create api key with terraform. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60828348/can-i-create-gcp-api-keys-using-terraform

Answer (score 2):

I guess the service ID you're looking for is `maps-backend.googleapis.com` or `static-maps-backend.googleapis.com` if you want to generate static maps.

```
➜  ~ gcloud services list --available |grep maps
maps-android-backend.googleapis.com                                                                  Maps SDK for Android
maps-backend.googleapis.com                                                                          Maps JavaScript API
maps-embed-backend.googleapis.com                                                                    Maps Embed API
maps-ios-backend.googleapis.com                                                                      Maps SDK for iOS
static-maps-backend.googleapis.com                                                                   Maps Static API
```

I've got these result with Google Cloud SDK version 360.0.0, also there is `apikeys.googleapis.com` service available with `alpha` component which makes me think it could be achievable by using [gcloud module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-google-modules/gcloud/google/latest) and `gcloud alpha services api-keys create` command.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the similar problem recently, but fixed it by providing additional roles to the service account. I am not sure what permissions you need, you need to look it up. In my case, I was trying to create an appengine project, So I had to add "Appengine Admin" role to the service account and enable "appengine.googleapis.com" via terraform resource "google_project_service"

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Ahmet! I put up a bounty for this question and Ahmet came through with a great answer. I tried the `gcloud` module for terraform and it worked! However I needed to go a step further as the gcloud command wasn't able to save the output and also couldn't read the file due to permission issues. So I actually took the concept and used the `local-exec` in terraform instead to run a script which does all the gcloud commands I needed.

You can find a list of APIs here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/

Go into the documentation for the one you need and copy the url `*.googleapis.com`, in my example I needed the Geocoding API turned on and an API key for it.

```
# main.tf

module "project_services" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/project-factory/google//modules/project_services"
  version = "11.2.1"

  project_id = var.project_id
  activate_apis = [
    "geocoding-backend.googleapis.com",
  ]
  disable_dependent_services  = false
  disable_services_on_destroy = false
}

resource "null_resource" "geocode" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "chmod +x ./scripts/script.sh && sh ./scripts/script.sh"
    environment = {
      SERVICE_API = "geocoding-backend.googleapis.com"
      KEY_NAME = "my-key"
      SECRET_NAME = "my-secret"
    }
  }
  depends_on = [
    # e.g. module.secret_manager
  ]
}
```

Then you can create a script like so, with the environment variables being injected in:

```bash
# ./scripts/script.sh

GCLOUD_LOCATION=$(command -v gcloud)
echo "Using gcloud from $GCLOUD_LOCATION"

gcloud alpha services api-keys create --api-target=service="$SERVICE_API" --display-name="$KEY_NAME" &&
export KEY_NAME=$(gcloud alpha services api-keys list --format="value(name)" --sort-by createTime --limit 1) &&
export API_KEY=$(gcloud alpha services api-keys get-key-string $KEY_NAME --format="value(keyString)") &&
printf $API_KEY | gcloud secrets versions add "$SECRET_NAME" --data-file=-
```

My above script takes the key and inserts it into an existing Secret I created in terraform.